# How to make shared folders of different computers in a LAN available across two different networks, when only one PC has access to two networks?

Tags: windows, networking, bridging

I have a private network, in which only one of the computers connects to a public network (my workplace).

The structure is, more or less:

A <--- public(work) network ----> B <-----private network----->C

Computer A is random (with Windows). Computer B uses Windows 7. Computer C uses Windows XP.

Computer B has two network cards. One connects to the router on the work network, and the other directly to the network card of computer C.

I need this structure, because the computers in the private network should not be able to see the internet, and they are not allowed on the work network.

I currently can access B from A and C from B.

However, I would like to have access to the shared folder of C directly from A (from any computer on the work network, e.g. A). I wanted to do this by having the shared disk of C listed on the shared directory of computer B on the network.

Something like \computer B \ computer C.

This folder would have all data shared by computer C. The contents of this folder are physically stored on computer C, not B. In this way, C would only be visible if someone had the password for B.

Is there any way to do this without allowing computer C to be visible to the network, or allowing it to see the internet?

Thanks in advance =]

Comment: Put the folder/files you want to be accessed in both networks on the computer that is on both networks.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. However, I cannot do that because the files are too large and have to stay in the machines where they are generated. They cannot be stored on the machine that connects to both networks.

Comment: I have no idea whether it will work, but try putting a desktop shortcut (alias) on the common computer that can be accessed by both. Otherwise, big hard drives are not that expensive these days.

Answer (score 1):

In short: unfortunately not. This won't be possible through the windows network file system.

You do have a few work arounds. e.g. having a local copy of the files from computer C on computer B using a file sync to keep them up to date. You will need to add a HD to computer B if it does not have enough space. Or you might be able to use some third party distributed file software (but I haven't tried that myself yet). You could also use firewall to only allow specific communication between A and C (possibly there is a software firewall for windows you could use on computer B - it probable will have to be 3rd party though, I don't think the windows firewall rules would allow for such a setup).

The different solutions will have different up and downsides, but without more information on your restrictions it is not possible to give you a valid solution right away.